# How to stack multiple Astropy Tables

Tags: python, numpy, astropy

I have a for loop that generates several variables let say `a`, `b`, and `c`. I would like to
vertically stack the variables after the for loop gone trough the loops. Here what I would like to do. (let say the variables are just numbers (1,2,3) for sake of example).

```
from astropy.table import Table
N1 = 3
N2 = 5
a = zeros((N2,N1))
b = zeros((N2,N1))
c = zeros((N2,N1))
for i in range(N2):    
   a[i] = range(N1)
   b[i] = range(N1)
   c[i] = range(N1)
   t  = Table([a[i], b[i], c[i]], names=('a', 'b', 'c'), meta={'name': 'first table'})
```

at the moment when I `print t` I get

```
 a   b   c 
--- --- ---
0.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
2.0 2.0 2.0
```

What I want to get is the following;

```
 a   b   c 
--- --- ---
0.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
2.0 2.0 2.0
0.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
2.0 2.0 2.0
0.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
2.0 2.0 2.0
0.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
2.0 2.0 2.0
0.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
2.0 2.0 2.0
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Just as an aside, I updated the title of your question to not mention "for loops".  Generally a good question asks what it is you're actually trying to achieve, not how you think you want to achieve it (which might not be the best answer).  In this case there's no reason to use for loops at all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want for instance the number of rows repeat n=5 times you just need to use `vstack` , similar to `numpy.vstack` as following:

```
>>>from astropy.table import vstack
>>>t1=vstack([t,t,t,t,t])
>>>print t1

 a   b   c 
--- --- ---
0.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
2.0 2.0 2.0
0.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
2.0 2.0 2.0
0.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
2.0 2.0 2.0
0.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
2.0 2.0 2.0
0.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
2.0 2.0 2.0
```